# C# - Task Scheduling

Tags: c#, scheduling, scheduled-tasks

I am using Asp.Net - Web Forms - Framework 3.5

I want to send emails to web-site users at 12am mid night. I have made a class method that sends emails but what is best way to auto execute it at 12 mid night?

In linux we have cron jobs, what's on windows both dedicated and shared server?

Comment: You may want to either accept an answer that answered your question, or provide an answer of your own, explaining how you solved this question.

Answer (score 3):

Simplest way is to write a little command line app that sends emails, then use [Windows Task Scheduling](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Schedule-a-task) to run the app every day at midnight.

Comment: I don't think its allowed on shared hosting server .. isn't it ?

Comment: Maybe. You have very few options to run scheduled tasks on a shared host. It all depends on what your host allows.

Answer (score 2):

As a `cron` substitute you can try `at` command and run some executable which will send e-mails, or you can create a windows service to do this job.

Answer (score 2):

When on a shared host, with no access to the task scheduler, I've often times put some code in the Global.asax, which would create a new static Timer object in the OnStart of the application.  I would then run my class method every hour or so, when the Timer elapsed.

The downside to this, is that you have to keep your application pool running 24/7, otherwise it will spin down and your code won't run hourly.

An alternative, would be to make a page that runs the code from your class method, and trigger that page from an external source automatically at midnight each night.  You could just setup a wget/curl script to hit that URL programmaticly.

Lastly, you have other solutions, as detailed in this other post:
[Can you run a "service" that runs a scheduled task from an ASP.Net project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5904115/can-you-run-a-service-that-runs-a-scheduled-task-from-an-asp-net-project)

Answer (score 1):

Writing a windows service calling the code periodically for sending emails would do the job.

Comment: I don't think running windows service is allowed on shared hosting server .. isn't it ?

Comment: Yeah then how about creating a thread in global.asax and scheduling it on per day basis.

Answer (score 0):

You can use task scheduler which is the winnows equivalent of chron, or you can write a windows service that periodically checks the time and if it's after midnight, it can send emails.

You can't do this from your web form because that code only executes when a user is on the site, and it's very bad practice to leave a thread running; iis would probably recycle it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I've had some success using Quartz.NET, but the task scheduler and simple command line app combination as suggested by others is the simplest way to do it.

Comment: However, a command line app won't work in a shared hosting environment, which was a constraint of the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Create your application  in windows service and in app.config file use timer and set the timer to 12 midnight.

Answer (score -1):

If you need to run a scheduled task/cron job in a shared hosting environment, you'll find a list of free web cron job providers here:
[ASP.NET: Free scheduling of your tasks (Cron jobs)](http://www.lazerwire.com/2011/10/aspnet-free-scheduling-of-your-tasks.html)